# Is 'name' a reserved word in URL's?

Tags: urls

I'm creating some custom templates and I keep running in to a problem where I get'Page not found'. After a bit of debugging, I discovered that I only get this if my URL contains `www.mysite.com/custom_page/?name=donkey_boy`.

If I use `www.mysite.com/custom_page/?full_name=donkey_boy`, the page loads as it should.

Does that mean that `name` is a reserved word?

Comment: Yes it is, and there are a few more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this'll solve your query... [WordPress Reserved Terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms). Just search for 'name', it's there.

Comment: Isn't that only variables concerning `taxonomies`? They  mention something about `reserved WordPress public and private query variables`, but that link is broken.

Comment: Yes, indeed this page points to 'Taxonomies' only, but I just meant to bring it to notice that if 'name' is a reserved term here, it may be, in other contexts too. Precisely, it exists as a reserved term in WordPress universe. And the link works fine! ;)

Comment: hmm...ok, I'll look into this. And no, the content in that link is "broken" `Trac Error. No node trunk/wp-includes/classes.php at revision 18517`